# JSON serialization exception when passing complex Model object to SignalR 2 client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I get a 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' when passing an instance of the following Model class to SignalR 2 client:

```html
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class SensorCheckpoint
    {
        public int SensorCheckpointID { get; set; }
        public int SensorStatus { get; set; }
        public int LineMount { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Line Line { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The exception is not raised, however, if I instead pass a simpler version of the object:

```html
namespace MyApp
{
    public class SensorCheckpointPush
    {
        public SensorCheckpointPush(SensorCheckpoint s) {
            this.SensorNumber = s.SensorCheckpointID;
            this.SensorStatus = s.SensorStatus;
            this.LineMount = s.LineMount;
        }
        public int SensorNumber { get; set; }
        public int SensorStatus { get; set; }
        public int LineMount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to pass Model objects to the client? If so, how is it done? (I am following the StockTicker sample, where only simple objects are passed). What would be the pattern for sending database objects to SignalR client?
I've spent hours trying to find answers for this.

Stack Trace is:

```html
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in System.Web.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: What is the exception message? Stack trace?

Comment: And also, what values did the properties have?  And also where is the rest of the `SensorCheckPoint` class (since I notice it is partial).

Comment: The exception is: A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll. The class is partial because it is auto-generated by the Entity Framework. . .I don't know what is in the rest of it. . .